# Can someone help me understand why im getting an error here I believe its because of the appointment singly linked list

Tags: c++, file, fstream, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

IM getting an error that the apointment isnt initialized but idk what to do about when i remove the whole appointment part , the code works perfectly . I tried everything but i have no idea what to do since im still a beginner so any help is appreciated ! thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Appointment;
struct Time {
    int Day, Hour, Minute, Second;
};


struct Employee {
    int UniqueID;
    string FirstName,LastName, EmailAddress;
     Appointment* Calendar;
    Employee* next;
    Employee* previous; 
};

struct Company {
    Employee* head, * tail;
};

struct Appointment {
    string Title;
    Time StartingTime;
    int Duration;
    Appointment* next;
};


Company* InitializeDoubly() {
    Company* c = new Company;
    c->head = NULL;
    c->tail = NULL;
    return c;
}

Appointment* Init() {
    return NULL;
}


bool isEmpty(Company *c){
    return(c->head == NULL);
}

void InsertAtDoublyTail(Company* c, Employee e) {
    Employee* tmp = new Employee;
        tmp->UniqueID = e.UniqueID;
        tmp->FirstName = e.FirstName;
        tmp->LastName = e.LastName;
        tmp->EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress;
        tmp->Calendar->StartingTime.Day = e.Calendar->StartingTime.Day;
        tmp->Calendar->StartingTime.Hour = e.Calendar->StartingTime.Hour;
        tmp->Calendar->StartingTime.Minute = e.Calendar->StartingTime.Minute;
        tmp->Calendar->StartingTime.Second = e.Calendar->StartingTime.Second;
        tmp->Calendar->Duration = e.Calendar->Duration;
        tmp->previous = c->tail;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        c->tail->next = tmp;
        c->tail = tmp;
}


void head2tail(Company* c) {
    Employee* cur = c->head;
    
    if (isEmpty(c)) {
        cout << "LIST IS EMPTY";
        return;
    } 
    while (cur != NULL) {
        cout << cur->UniqueID << " " << cur->FirstName << " " << cur->LastName << " " <<
            cur->EmailAddress << " " << cur->Calendar->Title << " " << cur->Calendar->StartingTime.Day << " "
            << cur->Calendar->StartingTime.Hour<<" " << cur->Calendar->StartingTime.Day <<" "<< cur->Calendar->StartingTime.Second
            <<" " << cur->Calendar->Duration<<endl;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}


void parsefile(Company *c) {
    fstream f("file1.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    Employee efile;
    
    string id,day, hour, minute, second;
    
    while (f) {
        getline(f, efile.FirstName,'\t');
        getline(f, efile.LastName, '\t');
        getline(f, efile.EmailAddress, '\t');
        getline(f, efile.Calendar->Title, '\t');
        getline(f, id, '\t');
        getline(f, day, '\t');
        getline(f, hour, '\t');
        getline(f, minute, '\t');
        getline(f, second, '\t');
        f >> efile.Calendar->Duration; 

        efile.UniqueID = stoi(id);
        efile.Calendar->StartingTime.Day = stoi(day);
        efile.Calendar->StartingTime.Hour = stoi(hour);
        efile.Calendar->StartingTime.Minute = stoi(minute);
        efile.Calendar->StartingTime.Second = stoi(second); 
        InsertAtDoublyTail(c, efile);
        f.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }
    f.close();
}



int main()
{
    Company* company1 = InitializeDoubly();
    parsefile(company1);
}
```

Maybe the problem is that appointment isnt initialized right or should be initialized in the main fucntion perhaps but i tried it and im still getting the same error about something being wrong with thr initialization

Comment: Can you add the exact error message including line numbers? I see several issues here.

Comment: @whiplash  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26495 Variable 'Employee::UniqueID' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\user\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 20 
    }
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26495 Variable 'Employee::previous' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\user\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp 20

Comment: Can you provide a link to you file1.txt? So that we can test some changes

Comment: @whiplash [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9fc1c7d632cbf1373397183057f6c76c20211218070300/d7b2e0) here is the link of the file

Comment: Lol. No. I have been working on it for the past hour

Comment: Did you test your code with calling `head2tail()` on your company object without the Appointment part? I feel like that part isn't working either.

Comment: @whiplash thank you man it worked . Really appreciate the help and sorry for making you work for the past few hours lol !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Employee` structure, your `Appointment* Calendar;` is set to NULL by default. So in your `parsefile()` function, when you do `getline(f, efile.Calendar->Title, '\t');` that is an obvious Segmentation Fault because your `efile.Calendar` is NULL.

Also, it might be a good idea to use `istringstream` to parse your string instead of using `getline()` with the delimiter. This is also shown in official documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/130870/)

Modify your `parsefile` method like this:

```
void parsefile(Company *c) {
    fstream f("file1.txt", ios::in);
    Employee efile;
    
    string id,day, hour, minute, second;
    string line; // USED TO READ THE ENTIRE LINE
    while (getline(f, line)) {
        std::istringstream iline(line); // CONVERT IT TO istringstream
        string nextWord = ""; // Used to read every word in the line
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        efile.FirstName = nextWord; // Set first name
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        efile.LastName = nextWord; // Set last name
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        efile.EmailAddress = nextWord;

        // For the Appointment part, create a temporary Appointment variable similar to efile for Employee
        Appointment* temp = new Appointment();
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        temp->Title = nextWord; // Set the Title

        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        efile.UniqueID = stoi(nextWord);

        Time t; // Create a temporary time object like efile or temp
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        t.Day = stoi(nextWord);
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        t.Hour = stoi(nextWord);
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        t.Minute = stoi(nextWord);
        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        t.Second = stoi(nextWord);

        temp->StartingTime = t; // Set the Time data member of temp to the temporary object you just constructed.

        getline(iline, nextWord, '\t');
        temp->Duration = stoi(nextWord); // Set the duration

        efile.Calendar = temp; // Now set the Calendar data member to the temporary Appointment* object you just created
        InsertAtDoublyTail(c, efile); // Add it to the file
    }
    f.close();
}
```

This will now ensure that you are allocating the correct memory for every pointer you are using before performing any operation on it. In your `InsertAtDoublyTail(Company *c, Employee e)` you don't have to do a hard copy every attribute inside the pointers.

Another problem that I see in your code is that in your `head2tail` method, you are using the starting point as `Employee* cur = c->head;` but nowhere in your code are you assigning anything to `c->head`. This means that `c->head` will always be NULL and hence nothing will actually print.

One more issue that I see is that in your `InsertAtDoublyTail(Company* c, Employee* e)`, you have this:

```
tmp->previous = c->tail;
tmp->next = NULL;
c->tail->next = tmp;
c->tail = tmp;
```

For the first employee that you add to the company, `c-tail` will be NULL. So `c->tail->next = tmp` will result in a Segmentation Fault. You need to modify your function like this:

```
void InsertAtDoublyTail(Company* c, Employee e) {
    Employee* tmp = new Employee(); // Create the employee pointer and set all the values.
    tmp->UniqueID = e.UniqueID;
    tmp->FirstName = e.FirstName;
    tmp->LastName = e.LastName;
    tmp->EmailAddress = e.EmailAddress;
    tmp->Calendar = e.Calendar;
    // Add the employee to company
    tmp->previous = c->tail;
    if(c->tail == NULL) { // This means that there is absolutely nothing in the list yet. So assign head and tail to the same tmp that you just created
        c->tail = tmp;
        c->head = tmp; // This needs to be done for your head2tail to work. Without this, your c-> head will be NULL always meaning nothing will print.
    }
    else { // This means that there is at least one Employee in the company. So don't touch the head. Add the new employee to the tail and then just modify the c->tail to point to the last employee that you just added.
        c->tail->next = tmp;
        c->tail = tmp;
    }
}
```

This should fix everything. When I run the entire code, (after adding more rows to the file1.txt) I see this:

```
1 sara laban sara@gmail.com business 20 5 20 10 3000             
2 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000              
3 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000
4 sara laban sara@gmail.com business 20 5 20 10 3000
5 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000
6 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000
7 sara laban sara@gmail.com business 20 5 20 10 3000
8 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000
9 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000
10 sara laban sara@gmail.com business 20 5 20 10 3000
11 Rami lawen alwdij@gmail.com marketing 50 5 50 10 5000
```